# Solving for $x$ in $x^{\ln(x)}=ex$

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms

So I was again looking through the homepage of Youtube when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/5bDa8WrxFDM) video by SyberMath which proposed the question$$\text{Solve: }x^{\ln(x)}=ex$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving the aforementioned equation:$$x^{\ln(x)}=ex$$

---

$$\ln\left(x^{\ln(x)}\right)=\ln(e\cdot x)$$

---

$$\ln(x)\ln(x)=\ln(e)\cdot\ln(x)$$

---

$$(\ln(x))^2=\ln(x)$$

---

$$\frac{(\ln(x))^2}{\ln(x)}=1$$

---

$$\ln(x)=1$$

---

$$e^{\ln(x)}=e^1$$

---

$$e=x$$

---

$$\mathbf{\text{My question}}$$

---

Is the solution that I have arrived at correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution/attain it more easily?

Comment: If you plug $x=e$ in your original equation you can clearly see it is not satisfied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not correct. You failed here:
$$\ln(e\cdot x)\neq\ln e\cdot \ln x$$
Here is the solution:
$$x^{\ln(x)}=ex$$
$$\ln\left(x^{\ln(x)}\right)=\ln(e\cdot x)$$
$$\ln(x)\ln(x)=\ln(e)+\ln(x)$$
$$\ln^2(x)=1+\ln x$$
$$\ln^2(x)-\ln(x)-1=0$$
now take $\ln x=y$:
$$y^2-y-1=0$$
which is clearly solved by $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
So now you have $$\ln(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Exponentiate and you get:
$$x=e^\phi,\ e^{-\frac{1}{\phi}}$$

Comment: You beat me! Argh! Anyway, it is pretty interesting that $\phi$ decided to show up.

Comment: Yea, it is almost everywhere.